# Bootstrap Carousel and JQuery "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I could like my carousel to only move forward IF a form is filled out entirely.  I've tried using the slid and slide methods as well as previus, next and pause.  With the following code, I achieve the functionality and user experience I want but there is a console error that I am concerned with

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The error does not seem to affect anything right now but I'm sure it will in production or somewhere down the line.

JS

```
// when my carousel is clicked to slide forward
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  // find the active carousel item
$(".item").each(function(i11,e12){
  if ($(e12).hasClass("active")){
        // if the first input is blank 
        if ($(e12).find("input:first").val() === ""){
           // then pause the carousel and go back
       $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
       $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
        };      
      };
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-off-screen form-group" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
```

This has the correct effect of the carousel moving to the next slide then pausing and returning so then I can tell the user to correctly enter the fields.  But, I am curious as to how to fix the error.

http://jsfiddle.net/v87cL/3/

Comment: I would guess you're triggering the `slide` event again when you call `prev`, and again and again *ad infinitum*. What happens if you simply `return false` within the event handler?

Comment: I added return false and nothing changed after $('.carousel').carousel('prev');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're triggering the `slide` event again when you call `prev`, and again and again *ad infinitum*.

Instead of pausing and going back, cancel the event with `return false;` or use `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    console.log(e); 
    $('.item.active',this).each(function(i,el) {
        if ($(el).find('input:first').val()==='') {
             e.preventDefault();   
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/v87cL/

Comment: Thank you for helping! I tried e.preventDefault(); and added (e) to my function and also tried return false; Neither prevent the carousel from moving forward.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `pause` and `prev` commands completely.

Comment: If you're still having problems, something else is going on. Can you recreate your code at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I did but the carousel is stilling moving onward. When I logged (e) to my console it showed ce.Event {type: "slide", relatedTarget: div.item.next.left, direction: "left", timeStamp: 1400091650636, jQuery110207286902389023453: true…}

Comment: I updated your Jfiddle to include logic to check if a field is filled and it does not work so it should be a good demo of my own issue http://jsfiddle.net/v87cL/3/

Comment: You have to save the fiddle and post the new URL.

Comment: That fiddle has no form elements, so of course your code doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/v87cL/5/

Comment: I of course also added the input field to the jfiddle. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: *That* code block had a syntax error -- you didn't close the event handler. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/v87cL/9/ -- but see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/v87cL/) for several small optimizations.

Comment: I apologie and appreciate your help.  I am multitasking as usual and apologize for my errors. You inspired me to look at the problem different as there is probably a bug going on.  Since your answer solved the problem as it was stated without other bugs I will mark it as correct.  I will also post my solution which was to use the slid method and not the slide method. That way it executes after the slide completes, checks the input of the slide, and moves it back if not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution was to use the slid method and not the slide method. That way it executes after the slide completes, checks the input of the slide, and moves it back if not complete.

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    $(".item").each(function(i11,e12){
        if ($(e12).hasClass("active")){
            if ($(e12).prev().find("input:first").val() === ""){
              $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
            };
        };
    });
});
```